# How say 'Requested By' with one word?

Tags: word-request

How can I express the term "Requested By" with one word? I would like to use it in programming so the word should be as short as possible.

Some type of objects would have this property what what would tells me, which other object requested the creation of that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call it [***requester***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/request#request_1), a noun derived from *request* meaning "the entity that did the requesting". (requestor is an alternative, less-common variant).

Or, since it's in a programming context, you could use ***caller*** since presumably the "requested by" object called a constructor to create the requested object.

Finally, you could go simple with ***creator***.

Answer (score -1):

Try using 'needs' or 'needed' as I presume that is why 'it' was 'requested by' the 'requester'

Comment: Need and request are hardly synonymous.